# Plotly charts not showing when sharing jupyter notebook in IBM Cloud Pak for data

Tags: plotly-python

Here is the notebook: https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/1c96e62e-553b-4f04-b851-95c5621a3483/view?access_token=d92c1c0fe2fab7ee9647499a5280a6faa8e77f4fe244bdf8ad10cc5be4efb361

I import the necessary libraries, namely:

```
!pip install plotly #==4.9.0 # map rendering for nicer looking maps

import plotly.express as px # map rendering for bubble plot
import plotly.offline as pyo # map rendering for offline viewing
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
```

Then I define the plots ( at the bottom of the notebook ):

Then I attempt to render them for sharing purposes:
pyo.iplot(figa)
pyo.iplot(figb)

What am I missing? Can a shared notebook show the

Answer (score 0):

The shared notebook will need to be marked as "Trusted" or the output will not be displayed.

[Per Documentation here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook.html#trusting-notebooks)

"Trusting Notebooks
To prevent untrusted code from executing on users’ behalf when notebooks open, we store a signature of each trusted notebook. The notebook server verifies this signature when a notebook is opened. If no matching signature is found, Javascript and HTML output will not be displayed until they are regenerated by re-executing the cells."

Comment: Thank you for responding. To clarify plotly works perfectly in the notebook, it just doesn't render when visited through the shared link and a viewer has no ability to trust the notebook. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that I can force trust on the shared side of the notebook. Alas, foiled by good safety protocols. I hope there is another work around. Not sure if I need to port to some kind of widget.